# Updating record in multiple table

Tags: php, mysql

I have here 4 tables. Table1 is my main table, If I update record in table1, all others tables that has the same record should update too. But what if some record are not in others tables. Like in my table structure below, `Ballpen` was not in the table3. Should I used LEFT JOIN? Any help?

**Table 1**

```
|--------------|--------------|
|  Description |     Code     |
|--------------|--------------|
|    Ballpen   |    X2300B    |
|--------------|--------------|
|    Pencil    |    C9990C    |
|--------------|--------------|
```

**Table 2**

```
|--------------|--------------|
|  Description |     Code     |
|--------------|--------------|
|    Ballpen   |    X2300B    |
|--------------|--------------|
```

**Table 3**

```
|--------------|--------------|
|  Description |     Code     |
|--------------|--------------|
|    Pencil    |    C9990C    |
|--------------|--------------|
```

**Table 4**

```
|--------------|--------------|
|  Description |     Code     |
|--------------|--------------|
|    Ballpen   |    X2300B    |
|--------------|--------------|
|    Pencil    |    C9990C    |
|--------------|--------------|


$sql = $mysqli->query("
UPDATE  
        table1 t1
INNER JOIN
        table2 t2
ON      t2.code= t1.code
INNER JOIN
        table3 t3
ON      t3.code= t1.code
INNER JOIN
        table4 t4
ON      t4.code= t1.code
SET     t2.code = '$new_value'
")or die('There was an error running the query [' . $mysqli->error . ']');
```

Comment: what are you doing for achieving it??? Post your solution.

Comment: Learn about normalization.  The primary purpose of a normalized database is so any one data item is stored in one place -- that makes it much easier to update and keep in sync.

Comment: `Foreign keys` might help.

Comment: @CEP yah I know how to use that. But my question is how if one of the table don't have that foreign key?